# MVC / ASP.NET design templates

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Does anyone know of any good sites to download good design templates (master pages, css files) for MVC projects, or ASP.NET projects in general?  I've used the asp.net mvc gallery but the options there are pretty limited.  I'm willing to pay for some if they are good.

Answer (score 6):

http://www.templatemonster.com

cheap and pretty [professional](http://www.templatemonster.com/website-templates.php).

Comment: Do they have an ASP.NET specific section, with MasterPages etc?

Comment: You can't make a "universal" master page.  That is like trying to make a template that works on drupal, wordpress and joomla.

Comment: I've used that before.  Was kind of hoping to find for ASP.NET specific ones.

Comment: envalid - not looking for "Universal"...just "ASP.NET" specific ones, much like the MVC design gallery on microsoft's site.

Comment: They're almost all available in plain HTML. So creating a masterpage from any of them should be very easy.

Comment: lol.. why did I get -1? oh well.

Comment: I think these guys have what you want, for MVC C# or VB. http://wiwet.com/

Answer (score 5):

take a look at this project : http://mvccontribgallery.codeplex.com/

there are many ASP.NET MVC design samples inside this project.

Answer (score 4):

I've easily fitted templates from the likes of [Free CSS Templates](http://www.freecsstemplates.org/) in to numerous ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC sites - they are very clean HTML and CSS templates, often built around common elements, so that once you've built your MasterPage changing to another one is often as simple as updating the CSS reference and changing some images.

Obviously there's a bit more work if you want to swap from a horizontal to vertical navigation, but it's not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

All of the best examples of websites built on ASP.NET are hosted on [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/).  Take a look at BlogEngine.Net if you are wanting a good ASP.NET example website or if you are looking for a specific library or type of ASP.NET MVC site then you can use the sites search capabilities to find whatever you are looking for.  CodePlex is the site for open source .Net technologies like ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC.  ASP.NET MVC futures is also hosted at codeplex if you are looking for additional features